# Java Timer For Game for food system

Tags: java, timer

I need a java timer to recognize when it hits a certain time for the game I am making. I am new to timers and I was wondering if this code works somehow. I need the if statement to work.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(whatevergoeshere,this);
public void farmingTimer()
{
     timer.start();
     if(timer == 1000)
     {
          food++;
          timer.restart();
          timer.start();
     {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a good example [page](https://java2blog.com/java-timer-example/).
But I don't think you should be using timers for this kind of thing. You are probably better off updating things as often as you can, and keeping track of the time between updates. Then in the object that has then timer in, can just keep track of the amount of time passed.

```
public class FoodTimer
{

      public int food = 0;
      private double timer = 0;
      public void update(double dt)
      {
           timer += dt;
           if(timer > 1000)
           {
                 food++;
                 timer = 0;
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this might help but will I be able to run this multiple times at once. Say if you make multiple farms?

Comment: Yes, you just need multiple instances of this class.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this: [How to setup a timer (Java 7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

What you basically want to do is create an instance of the class Timer eg:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

In your question above, your constructor call used two parameters. If you read the docs, you will find out those two parameters accept a string (name) and a boolean (isDaemon) eg

```
Timer(String name, boolean isDaemon)
```

If you want to learn more about daemon threads, I suggest you read this article: [Daemon Threads in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/daemon-thread-java/).

Now, once you have your instance ready, do this:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { //scheduleAtFixedRate means execution will repeat
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //your code here eg food++;
        }
    }, 0, 60*1000); // the two values at the end are delay and period - delay is 0 seconds and period states that the block will be executed every minute (both values are in milliseconds)
```